docker file not copying files over with COPY
This is part of my docker file:
USER root

COPY actions /actions

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

When I build the image I am in the right directory and can see the actions folder and entrypoint.sh file. This has previously worked. What might be the issue?
I navigate into the container with docker exec -it /bin/bash but the files are not there
EDIT:
The problem seems to be in 'botpress/server:v12_31_5' when i change FROM botpress/server:v12_31_5 to FROM ubuntu:22.04 the files copy over fine
I tried different versions of botpress but the same error

How are you checking that the files are not there. If there was no error the copy did succeed so perhaps there's a problem with how you validated the issue.

I run the container with -it and /bin/bash. And list the files. They used to appear but they don't anymore. But when switching to a different base image and validating the same way, I can see the files there

Your comment helped me, when I run with /bin/bash I'm not inside the root directory like I thought. I need to change where the files are copied to by the looks of things. I'm inside a botpress folder

That was my hunch. Glad you figured it out
